# Calculate angle between player and end point

Tags: c#, c++

I have such question:

how to calculate angle between player and end point?

Things, which i have:

1. Player. I have X, Y, Z position of player and his Z-angle (0-360)
2. Endpoint. I have only X, Y, Z position of end point.

Task:

Rotated player Z-angle to end point.

How i can did this?

Please, help :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want

```
z_angle = atan2(target_y - player_y, target_x - player_x);
```

Comment: Don't forget to take the player's current facing angle into account!